# getErrorStream: stream closed, getInputStream: works

Tags: java, stream, httpconnection

I have a weird issue with my code:

```
URL url = new URL(searchUrlPOST.replace("%accessToken", accessToken));
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setConnectTimeout(5000);
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
conn.setDoOutput(true);
conn.setDoInput(true);
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
os.write(json.getBytes("UTF-8"));
os.close();

// read the response
InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
```

That works perfectly fine as long as the server is responding with a proper status code. If he however responds with something like a 400 and i replace the `conn.getInputStream()` with a `conn.getErrorStream()` I get a

> Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Stream closed

How come?

Comment: Have you tried it with curl or something similar?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but:

Please make sure that

> searchUrlPOST.replace("%accessToken", accessToken)

returns a valid url, this error can been thrown by using an invalid url at "new Url(String url)"

Comment: It does return a 400 error which is fine, vbut I still need the content of that.

Comment: A 400 error means that there went something wrong at the server side, please check your server's log for an error. I can help you with that too if you want :)

Comment: Sir, a error 400 does not mean something is wrong at the server, a 500 does. Besides that, as I said, the error is expected and still respons a body which I need to get. That's the only issue here.

Comment: Sorry, Error 400 means bad request, what request parameters are you using and are all the values URL encoded?

Comment: Not to be rude but please read what I need. It does not matter what the issue is that is causing the 400, I just want to grab the error message that the server is returning. Ignore everything else.

Comment: url.getErrorStream() should do the trick ( https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html#getErrorStream() )

Comment: Sorry sir but that is completely wrong. I appreciate your effor but I need someone to answer who actually knows what's up.