# POST JSON and retrieve JSON response, even on 40X errors

Tags: java, json, httprequest

I have been trying to accomplish what the title says for hours now, but nothing works. Been trying all sorts of different HTTP clients with all sorts of different errors. Related questions:

[getErrorStream: stream closed, getInputStream: works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35071191/geterrorstream-stream-closed-getinputstream-works/)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35065591/apache-http-client-get-body-on-error

Unfortunately there are no answers on both of the questions. Is there someone who can actually give me a working solution? I know Stackoverlflow is not a "asking for code" platform but it is quite obvious that I tried solving it on my own.

I just want to submit JSON data to a server and get the response (which is also in JSON) even on 40X errors (as the server still returns JSON data).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jersey Client would be my answer

https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/client.html

**Example:**

```
ClientConfig clientConfig = new ClientConfig();     
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient(clientConfig);

WebTarget webTarget = client.target("http://example.com/rest");
WebTarget resourceWebTarget = webTarget.path("resource");
WebTarget helloworldWebTarget = resourceWebTarget.path("helloworld");
WebTarget helloworldWebTargetWithQueryParam =
        helloworldWebTarget.queryParam("greeting", "Hi World!");

Invocation.Builder invocationBuilder =
        helloworldWebTargetWithQueryParam.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE);
invocationBuilder.header("some-header", "true");

Response response = invocationBuilder.post(Entity.entity("{'my':'json'}", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE));
System.out.println(response.getStatus());
System.out.println(response.readEntity(String.class));
```

Whatever the status of the response `response.getStatus()` you can get the body of the response `response.readEntity(String.class)`

Comment: Thanks but I tried already 3 different ones as well as Java HTTLUrlConnection and everything had a different issue. Please be more specific why you think this would work, besides the fact that I would really appreciate a example, I am very tired but need to get this done asap :(